# pandas faster way than argsort to rank in dataframe subset

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have this dataframe:

```
user1    user2   quantity
--------------------------
Alice    Carol     10
Alice    Bob       5
Bob      Dan       2
Carol    Eve       7
Carol    Dan      100
```

I want to rank the each row in descending order, using the quantity, BUT by user 1. Example:

```
user1    user2   quantity   order
----------------------------------
Alice    Carol     10       1
Alice    Bob       5        2
Bob      Dan       2        1
Carol    Eve       7        2
Carol    Dan      100       1
```

Currently, my code goes like this:

```
users = df['user1'].unique()
for user in users:
    cond = (df['user1'] == user)
    sort_ser = df[cond]['quantity'].values.argsort()[::-1] # descending
    df.loc[cond, 'order'] = sort_ser + 1
```

It works -- for small dataframes. But it's slow if it's for large ones. I think it's because (1) I'm essentially running it per user, and (2) several sorts are taking place. Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
df['order'] = df.groupby('user1')['quantity'].rank(ascending=False).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   user1  user2  quantity  order
0  Alice  Carol        10      1
1  Alice    Bob         5      2
2    Bob    Dan         2      1
3  Carol    Eve         7      2
4  Carol    Dan       100      1
```

Details.

```
df.groupby('user1')['quantity'].rank(ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    1.0
Name: quantity, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice answer - worth checking out what the tie-break mechanism in `rank` is by default (averaging) in case that isn't what is desired.

Comment: I'm actually running the code now on the dataset that I have. Earlier I think I was doing 100+ minutes -- and I still wasn't done. I'll post what happens with the revised code, but I'm optimistic.

Answer (score 0):

With some Numpy

```
a = np.lexsort([-df.quantity, df.user1])
u, idx, inv = np.unique(df.user1, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)

df.assign(order=a - idx.repeat(np.bincount(inv)) + 1)

   user1  user2  quantity  order
0  Alice  Carol        10      1
1  Alice    Bob         5      2
2    Bob    Dan         2      1
3  Carol    Eve         7      2
4  Carol    Dan       100      1
```